# Why does XMLHttpRequest variable become 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Running this code in console gives an error: `Cannot read property 'status' of undefined`.

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // global variable
xhr.open('GET', '/');
xhr.onload = function(){
    console.log(xhr.status); // this line throws the error
    var xhr = 'a'; // local variable
}
xhr.send();
```

If I comment out the line `var xhr = 'a';`, it works. Can someone explain what happens here?

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: When you reference a name, you’re referencing the one in the closest scope, even if the line with the `var` (or `let`, `const`, or `function`) is after the reference. That the reference is valid with `var` is known as “hoisting”. If you have the browser support, use `let` (and never `var`, anywhere) to get a better error.

Comment: @Ry- I don' think that's it. Try changing console.log(xhr.status) to console.log(xhr). It should print 'a', but it doesn't.

Comment: The declaration is hoisted, but the assignment isn’t. It acts like `var xhr; console.log(xhr.status); xhr = 'a';`. If this behaviour strikes you as never useful, you’re not wrong, which is why it was fixed with `let`.

Comment: @Ry- yeah I was trying to figure out when it can be useful but cannot think of any case.. Thanks!